# Consider duplicate index in drop_duplicates method of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

The `drop_duplicates` method of a Pandas DataFrame considers all columns (default) or a subset of columns (optional) in removing duplicate rows, and cannot consider duplicate index.

I am looking for a clean one-line solution that considers the index and a subset or all columns in determining duplicate rows.  For example, consider the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], data={'A': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'B': [1, 0, 0, 0]})
   A  B
a  0  1
b  0  0
b  0  0
c  0  0
```

Default use of the `drop_duplicates` method gives

```
df.drop_duplicates()
   A  B
a  0  1
b  0  0
```

If the index is also considered in determining duplicate rows, the result should be

```
df.drop_duplicates(consider_index=True) # not a supported keyword argument
   A  B
a  0  1
b  0  0
c  0  0
```

Is there a single method providing this functionality, that is better than my current approach:

```
df['index'] = df.index
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
del df['index']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `reset_index` and `duplicated`, and then index the original:

```
df = df[~df.reset_index().duplicated().values]
print (df)
   A  B
a  0  1
b  0  0
c  0  0
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates().set_index('[name_of_your_index_here]')
```

[output]

```
       A  B
index      
a      0  1
b      0  0
c      0  0
```

Comment: I upvoted the Answer above because the code ran faster
@coldspeed answer, `976 µs ± 5.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`
@Chris A answer, `1.41 ms ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`  
Of course, this ignores readability, and I don't think there is a clear winner there.